# #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, localhost

I installed Apache, MySQL, PHP, and phpmyadmin, and I did everything needed to make the localhost/phpmyadmin webpage work correctly, with the two user inputs, I remember making my password and username 'root', when I try to log in, I get the error in the title. I've have been searching for an hour for a solution, but nothing has worked for me, please someone help, this is so frustrating! Thanks in advance

PS. I also installed 'xampp' to start and stop mysql server (that's all I know how to use it for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you have not been able to put any valid data into your MySQL database. Therefore
you should definitely remove Apache, MySQL, PHP, and phpmyadmin, plus XAMPP; then restart your machine and install just XAMPP.

Getting all the necessary parts working together is tricky, that's why there are packages like XAMPP that do the work for you.

Comment: I removed everything, and installed wamp, thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

So you haven't managed to connect to the MySQL server through php myadmin, just get to the login screen?

The way you have phrased you question makes it sound like you've installed MySQL and php seperatly from xampp, is this the case as I believe that xampp comes with it's own versions?

You are on windows??

Comment: when I type 'root' in the MySQL command line app it works, i think

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with windows development I'm afraid but there's not really a need to have xampp installed and the stand alone applications. Xampp give you the full stack to use for development and mixing them by using xampp to start the stand alone mysql both will likely cause you some issues.

Comment: When I try to start apache on xampp i get `Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
00:42:54  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
00:42:54  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
00:42:54  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
00:42:54  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
00:42:54  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
00:42:54  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums`

Comment: How do I delete everything, so I start over again?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not overly familiar with installing and removing these applications from Windows. Are there any uninstall scripts in the application directories?